# Material UI unable to set default value on Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Form to set the value of `gender` autocomplete upon loading the data from API. But the autocomplete does not seem to set the data.
My main component looks like this:

```
// this function is used to set the default form values. for now, its just gender value
const setFormValues = () => {
       setValue("gender", {id: 'male', name: 'Male'})
    };
```

And in useEffect, I am running the above function whenever the data is done loading.

```
// prerequisites consists of many objects. gender is one of them
useEffect(() => {
        setFormValues();
    }, [prerequisites]);
```

Here is what the component looks like:

```
<Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({field: {onChange}}) => (
          <Autocomplete
            onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data?.[onChangeAttribute])}
            options={options || []}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} placeholder="test" label="test"/>}
          />
        )}
      />
```

I then went on to the documentation which pointed me to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx?file=/src/MuiAutoComplete.js). Basically, I can pass a default value. I then went on to creating a state and setting that state from the `setFormValues()` function. The state was being set correctly. But when I pass it to the `defaultValue`, the value is not being set and instead shows me the error uncontrolled component being used as a controlled component and use it as a controlled component instead.

**What I am trying to do:**

The idea I had in mind was to set the default value which is coming from an API call on useEffect. Basically, the page is the 'edit' page and I want to show the current selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing to set `value` prop on the `<Autocomplete />`.

```js
<Controller
  name={name}
  control={control}
  render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
    <Autocomplete
      onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data?.[onChangeAttribute])}
      options={options || []}
      value={value}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} placeholder="test" label="test"/>
      }
    />      
  )}
/>
```

Also you can just use RHF's `reset`, when your API call should return other form values.

```
useEffect(() => {
  reset(prerequisites);
}, [prerequisites]);
```

Comment: So in case the value is empty, it returns `The 'getOptionLabel' method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for "".`

Comment: If the `value` is empty, it should be a `null` value, so that the `<Autocomplete />` component can check that no value is provided. Otherwise it would think, that `""` is the actual value and then of course can't link it to any of your `options`. Check this working example of how to use a `<Autocomplete />` with RHF -> [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-mui-autocomplete-forked-hgewc?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I have changed everything and it works flawlessly. I just had one question which I could not find an answer for even in the official documentation.
What if I did not want to get an object in return and instead just work with the ID? So I am passing objects in to the options. I am then using `getOptionLabel` to set the label attribute (in my case name). the `value` returns an object and `onChange` should also be an object. What if I want only the `id` attribute to be set on change but still make the label and stuff work as normal? Edit: realized this doesn't make sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No your comment does make sense, but I would do that manipulation on the submit handler, and keep working with objects for your actual component.

Comment: @PICKAB00 not true, providing null, for objects not working...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the default value try to have a state with the default value you want and then set the `value={thestate}` so the `onChange` should change the same state.

Comment: Yes but then wouldn't it be outside of react hook form? I do not want to set it as a separate state and have all other inputs controlled by hook form.

Comment: This is the easy way but yes you are correct, in that case the pervious answer is the best.